# Replace integers with a string in python

Tags: python, regex, string, int

I have a string

```
string = "Files in this view are 168 hours away from being moved out of the active directory to the Recycle Bin."
```

I just want to replace the integer part `168` with some text at that place, we can find whether the string contains an integer or not like

```
bool(re.compile('\d').search(string))
```

But how to replace the integers in the above string with a another word/string like "`WOW Awesome`" and totally i want the result like

```
"Files in this view are WOW Awesome hours away from being moved out of the active directory to the Recycle Bin."
```

Comment: Use `re.sub` to replace using a regex search.

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.sub`

```
re.sub(r'\d+', 'Wow awesome', string)
```

Comment: aahhh thats very simple Thanks